# How can I automatically minimize all startup programs?

Tags: startup

I have set around five programs to run at startup and it's annoying when they take all my screen space. The worst offender is probably the Steam client that starts in fullscreen mode.
How can I automatically minimize all windows after signing in? Running a command at startup probably wouldn't work since not every programs starts instantly.

---

openSUSE 13.2
Display manager: GDM

Comment: On what operating system? Using what display manager? Please [edit] your question and give more details.

Comment: What's your desktop environment (e.g. Gnome, KDE, LXDE, …)? How did you set the programs to run at startup?